# Python deleting last index, without affecting other lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a program, where I have 2 lists. I wanted to remove the last index of one of these lists, but have encountered the problem, that the ways i tried deletes the content of every list.

Example:

```
list1 = ["Index", "2nd Index"]
list2 = list1
print(list1 == list2) #Here it is true, as it should be.

del list1[-1]
print(list1 == list2) #Here is still true, which it shouldn't be.
```

I tried to use `del`, `.pop()` and slicing. The only solution I have, is doing a .txt file and copy paste the first list into it and then copy paste everything into the second list. 
But there is surely another, easier, way, that doesn't require me doing a text file write a complete code section for copy pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Instead of `list2 = list1`, do `list2 = list1[:]`

---

tl;dr

In python, the variable name is just some pointer (not in the sense of `C`) pointing to the actual object that is holding the value of the variable. So when you do `variable_1 = variable_2`, you have two variables pointing at the same variable. You can see this behavior from the below example

```
a = 5
b = a
print(id(a), id(b)) #same identity
print(a is b) #True
```

If you do `b = 10` later, it will create a new object for `b` and `id(a)` and `id(b)` will no longer be equal. Same goes for lists.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = l1
id(l1), id(l2) #same identity
l1 is l2 #True
l2 = [2,3,4] #assign a new list
id(l1), id(l2) #different identities
l1 is l2 #False
```

But when you only change/delete...etc. a particular index of the list, the same list gets updated. You are not changing the variable `list2`

```
l2 = l1
l2.pop()
id(l1), id(l2) #same identity
l1 is l2 #True
```

Therefore you need to make a copy of the first list. `list2 = list1[:]` does that

Answer (score 0):

You don't have two lists, you have one list with two names.  Any time you do something to `list2` you're doing it to `list1` because they're the same list.

Try making `list2` a `copy`:

```
list1 = ["Index", "2nd Index"]
list2 = list1.copy()
print(list1 == list2) # Here it is true, what is totally fine now.

del list1[-1]
print(list1 == list2) # This is not true!
```

Comment: When i do this, it says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'.
Is this only for python 3?

Comment: Yup.  You can also do `list(list1)`, or `copy.copy` (need to `import copy` first), etc etc etc.  Google "copy a Python list", there are like a dozen ways to do it.  :)